# Play SoundEffect only on first time page load

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, windows-phone-7.1

WP7.5/Silverlight App...

On my page load, I play a Sound clip (e.g. Hello! Today is a wonderful day.)

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    seLoadInstance = seLoad.CreateInstance(); //I initialize this seLoad in Initialize method
    seLoadInstance.Play();
}
```

Now I have 3-4 other elements on the page. When user click on any of them, a sound clip for that element plays.

```
private void ElementClick_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    seElementInstance = seElement.CreateInstance();
    seElementInstance .Play();
}
```

**What I want is:**
When the page first loads and while the seLoadInstance is being played and user clicks the element, I don't want the seElementInstance to be played.

I can check the state of seLoadInstance like below to not play seElementInstance

```
private void ElementClick_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  if(seLoadTextInstance.State != SoundState.Playing)
  {     
        seElementInstance = seElement.CreateInstance();
        seElementInstance .Play(); 
   }
}
```

But the problem with above is that I have another element that can play the seLoadInstance on it's click.

**Problem:** I don't know how to differentiate if the seLoadInstance being played is first time or upon element click.

**Possible solution:** One way I see is using different instances to play the same sound.

I was hoping some better way like I set a flag upon load but I couldn't find any explicit event for SoundInstance completed or Stopped that I can handle.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a way using flag. Instead of setting a flag upon the firsttime load complete, I set the flag from one of my element that plays the seLoadTextInstance.

Something like below:

```
private bool isElementLoadSoundPlaying = false; //I set this to true below in another handler

private void ElementClick_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  //This if means LoadTextInstance is playing and it is the first time play
  if(seLoadTextInstance.State != SoundState.Playing && isElementLoadSoundPlaying == false )
  {     
     return;
  }
  seElementInstance = seElement.CreateInstance();
  seElementInstance .Play(); 
}

private void ElementLoadTextClick_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  isElementLoadSoundPlaying = true;
  seLoadInstance = seLoad.CreateInstance();
  seLoadInstance.Play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have not used sounds until now but what I have seen:

Why do you always create new instances when you want to play a sound?
Isn't it possible to create a instance for both "se"-elements and cust check if anyone is running before calling "play"?

For example:

```
private var seLoadInstance;
private var seElementInstance;

private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    seLoadInstance = seLoad.CreateInstance();
    seElementInstance = seElement.CreateInstance();

    seLoadInstance.Play(); // no need to check if something is playing... nothing will be loaded
}

private void ElementClick_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if(seLoadInstance.State != SoundState.Playing && seElementInstance.State != SoundState.Playing)
    {     
        seElementInstance .Play(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I would like to play the sound for the element being clicked i.e. stop any sound being played. The only time I don't want this to happen is upon first-time page load. As I mentioned before I am unable to use the State the way you mentioned. For Createing the new instance, I actually dispose the instance once it stops playing. I am not sure if that's a problem or wrong way of coding.